# How to add parameters to a api?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, rest, api

I am trying to study wordpress REST api

If I do:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories
```

I get all categories.

But let's say I want to exclude a category, according to the documentation it says:

```
exclude
Ensure result set excludes specific IDs.
```

So I try

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?exclude=697
```

I still get all categories, am I using wrongly the parameters?

Should it be written like

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/exclude=697
```

or

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories&exclude=697
```

[Here it is the doc](https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/)

Comment: Works for me: http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/categories | http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?exclude=2 (the second links excludes category id 2). By the way, that documention you're reading might not be up-to-date, read [the REST API documentation on WordPress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/) instead.

Comment: but how to add a parameter? if O wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ i get 10, but if I do wp-json/wp/v2/posts/per_page=-1 i get {"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Parametro(i) non valido(i): per_page","data":{"status":400,"params":{"per_page":"per_page non \u00e8 del tipo integer."}}} @cabrerahector

Comment: and if I do wp-json/wp/v2/posts?title I get all content and not just the titles, what am I doing wrong? @cabrerahector

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can't get all posts with the REST API. There's a "hardcoded" limit of a 100 posts per page (I think, not sure that's the actual number) that you can override via filter hooks. And to pass additional parameters, use `&`: `/categories?exclude=2&someOtherParam=someValue`.

Comment: @cabrerahector ok thanks, but why don't I only get the titles if I do wp-json/wp/v2/posts?title ?

Comment: Where did you read that by passing `title` to that endpoint the API would return post titles only? I don't see that mentioned on the [Posts Endpoint docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts).

Comment: @cabrerahector I see, that means basically the use of title in that case is only if we know the exact single tittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?exclude=2,11
```

It's the ids separated by comma. I get the categories filtered. Category 697 doesn't seem to exist in the API example.

When you do a GET request, you send the parameters in the [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). After the url, you end it with `?` and the assign the value of the parameter like this: `name_of_the_parameter=something`. If you have multiple parameters, you concatenate them with `&`, For example:

```
http://example.com/some/page?name=ferret&color=purple
```

Comment: but how to add a parameter? if O wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ i get 10, but if I do wp-json/wp/v2/posts/per_page=-1 i get {"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Parametro(i) non valido(i): per_page","data":{"status":400,"params":{"per_page":"per_page non \u00e8 del tipo integer."}}}

Comment: and if I do wp-json/wp/v2/posts?title I get all content and not just the titles, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: in regards of category 697 not existing, that's my category in my own enviroment I am trying

Comment: For the first question, It should be wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1 . For the second question, the docs (https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/) don't specify a 'title' parameter to just retrive the titles.

Comment: here it says title as a par https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

Comment: @rob.m please avoid asking multiples questions at once. Tackle one issue first, then ask a new question if you need help with something else.

Comment: @cabrerahector yeah I understand what you mean but tbh it is all about the same question I am asking and it's pointless to ask another question on SO for this. getting there tho, thanks

Comment: @monstercode the new API says categories_exclude and not just exclude, maybe better to edit your answer with the new refs, see https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

Comment: The docs that you posted (https://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/), under List Categorys, the parameter name is 'exclude'.